# Viewing Linux TCP TCB

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I need to find out information that should be kept in the TCP transmission control block (TCB), specifically I need to find out what sequence numbers are used for any particular session.

I have posted to other forums, looked through the procfs, searched Google, sent myself links from lmgtfy (dot) com :)  No luck.

If there is no tool or hints in the procfs, would it be possible to somehow find out where this sort of information exists in memory and gather it from there such as using to `dd` to copy /dev/mem?

Thanks for any help on this in advance!!!!!

Comment: Have you looked at the kernel source ? BTW I don't think the sequence numbers will be exposed via procfs, since they are too volatile, plus predicting them could be used as an attack vector for session hijacking (IIRC)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am hoping that someone has been through this before and has a quick answer or some feedback.  I have not looked through the source, to be honest I don't know if someone told me where in the source to look that I would be able to find it.

Comment: Somewhere in net/tcp/... , I guess. Grepping for seq[uence] will probably get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you first need to know what sequence number is and why it's been used, then you can look at particular implementation of sequence number generation.

Sequence numbers are 32 bit field and it's been used to mark every packet uniquely as if they can be acknowledged. And, being acknowledged
is important and it's an important feature of tcp for maintaining connection reliability. A full details could be found at the TCP rfc (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt - section 3.3).

Now if you need to find out how Linux does it, you need to look at net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c::tcp_v4_init_sequence() this is used for generating ISN (Initial Sequence Number) whenever a new connection to be established and how latter sequence numbers are generated that's explained at rfc. So, look at the implementation of tcp_v4_init_sequence() and rfc, that will help you to understand uses and implemetation of sequence number usefully. Hope this will help!